# Can I use loops to train my SVM model again?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, svm

I am doing text sentiment analysis using SVM for comparison with other methods
However, due to the large number of samples,
The following program makes me wait until the kernel crashes

```
tfhub_handle_preprocess="https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_zh_preprocess/3"
bert_preprocess_model = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess)

def encoder(strlist):
    return bert_preprocess_model(strlist)["input_word_ids"]

from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
SVM_Model = Pipeline([
    ('Encoder',FunctionTransformer(encoder)),
    ('Svm',SVC(kernel='linear'))
])


SVM_Model.fit(text,labels)
```

So I tried changing the program to something like this:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
for times in range(0,len(text),20):
    SVM_Model.fit(text[times:times+20],labels[times:times+20])
    pre = SVM_Model.predict(pre_text[:100])
    accuracy = accuracy_score(pre_labels[:100], pre)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    print(f'times:{times}, Accuracy:{accuracy}')
```

But I don't know if the SVM can be trained again like this,
or it will just ignore the previous samples.

Comment: I believe it will be refit on just the subset you give to it.